why doesn't check-parens and elisp syntax highlighting understand single-quoted symbols in lisp-interaction mode?
In a lisp interaction buffer, I'm finding that check-parens and the syntax highlighting don't understand single-quoted symbols. For example:
(secure-hash 'sha512 "not so random")

The syntax highlighting and the paren highlighting (I have show-paren-mode enabled) for that is wrong: if I have point at the end of that line, I see:

But with
(secure-hash (quote sha512) "not so random")

all works as expected.
The major mode is Lisp Interaction. If I change to lisp mode, the problem goes away; switching back to lisp interaction, I see it again. So perhaps a bug with lisp interaction mode?
For the "s" in "sha512", C-u C-x = gives:
             position: 3305 of 3317 (100%), column: 12
            character: s (displayed as s) (codepoint 115, #o163, #x73)
              charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x73
               script: latin
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Strong L2R, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 73" or "C-x 8 RET LATIN SMALL LETTER S"
          buffer code: #x73
            file code: #x73 (encoded by coding system utf-8)
              display: by this font (glyph code):
    harfbuzz:-outline-Cascadia Code Light-light-normal-normal-mono-13-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1 (#x17E)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN SMALL LETTER S
  general-category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
  decomposition: (115) ('s')

There is an overlay here:
 From 3293 to 3313
  face                 hl-line
  priority             -50
  window               #<window 8 on *scratch*>


There are text properties here:
  face                 font-lock-string-face
  fontified            t


and when on the closing paren, I get:
             position: 3315 of 3316 (100%), column: 22
            character: ) (displayed as )) (codepoint 41, #o51, #x29)
              charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x29
               script: latin
               syntax: )(   which means: close, matches (
             category: .:Base, >:Not at bol, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 29" or "C-x 8 RET RIGHT PARENTHESIS"
          buffer code: #x29
            file code: #x29 (encoded by coding system utf-8)
              display: by this font (glyph code):
    harfbuzz:-outline-Cascadia Code Light-light-normal-normal-mono-13-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1 (#x2F2)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: RIGHT PARENTHESIS
  old-name: CLOSING PARENTHESIS
  general-category: Pe (Punctuation, Close)
  decomposition: (41) (')')

There is an overlay here:
 From 3293 to 3317
  face                 hl-line
  priority             -50
  window               #<window 8 on *scratch*>


There are text properties here:
  face                 font-lock-string-face
  fontified            t

This seems like a bug in the highlighting, check-parens, and so on -- but it that seems like it's something that would have been fixed, so perhaps I'm doing something weird?
This is with emacs 29 on Windows.

Please fix link to screenshot.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

The question is unclear, and the image isn't visible.

Thanks for removing the lisp tag. The link to the screenshot should work now.

What is the major mode of the buffer and what minor modes are enabled in it? Can you do C-u C-x = on the closing paren and the s of sha512 and add the result to your question?

Thanks for updating the question. You didn't mention if you have any minor modes enabled (C-h m shows them all - you can fold each entry by clicking on the downward arrow image at the left of each entry to get a complete list). I have a raft of them enabled, but I still don't see what you see, so that might be the cause. Also, try to reproduce with emacs -Q and if you cannot, bisect your init file to find out what's causing it.
